# Error while copy and pasting components and pages - SDL Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, content-manager

we recently upgraded the Content Manager DB form Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Web 8.5 and Enabled Legacy Option too.

When user trying to copy and paste components and pages using tridion CME they receive Error ( Automation error), I will update the ticket more more details.

The user is able to create components and pages using the Menu and by using right click option.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs in the `LegacyEventAdapter`, which is used to trigger legacy, TOM/COM-based event handlers.

If you don’t such legacy event handlers, you can disable/remove this `LegacyEventAdapter` in the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file.

If you do still have such legacy event handlers (note that the new TOM.NET-based event system was introduced in 2011), the problem might be that the Legacy Pack has not been installed.

Note that SDL Web 8.5 is the last release that still has a Legacy Pack.

Comment: Rick thanks for the quick response. I did upgrade from SDL tridion 2011 sp1 to SDL web8.5 . I remember I did run the legecy Option true . We still have the Client having vb script and .net templates and we found some of the structure group was not loading . Do you think based on the error the legecy pack is not installed properly or completely not installed . Any specific items we need to select in advance settings what will be the impact if we install legecy pack? Thanks

Comment: You don’t need the `LegacyEventAdapter` if you (only) have VBScript Templates, but you will need the Legacy Pack.  What kind of error did you get for the problematic Structure Group?

Comment: @AnandNS You have mentioned you did upgrade from Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Web 8.5.
Note:
SDL Web supports only a specific set of upgrade paths to upgrade to SDL Web 8.5 :
You can upgrade to the current version of SDL Web (formerly called SDL Tridion) from the following versions:
SDL Web 8 with Cumulative Update 1 applied
SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 (Hotfix Rollup 1)

Comment: Yes I did follow the path during upgrade

Comment: @RickPannekoek I don’t get that error now but when I had asp and .net page under the SG it was not loading the entire SG and I think I run the CMS with legecy option .